# Windows 11 Slow Gradle Build Speed

Tags: android, windows, android-studio, gradle, windows-11

I have a very long gradle build speed on Android Studio (it doesn't depend on version) on Windows 11. I tried to reinstall drivers, reinstalled Windows 11. But the build speed still the same 11 minutes instead of 4. On Ubuntu build takes about 4 minutes. Is there any solution for this?

Tried to reinstall Windows.
Tried to set gradle parallel.
Changes several gradle versions.
Tried to set powerful battery mode.

Comment: You could try adding `--scan` to the build and then checking out the build scan on the Gradle website...  Comparing it from both a fast and slow system might at least give insight into which tasks(s) are contributing to the slowness.